# Access form element in ng-Submit

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular js and I am struck with accessing the form element in ng-submit function.
My intention is to set the action attribute dynamically and submit the form rather using jquery selector and setting the action attribute.

```
<div ng-app="MyApp">
    <form name="myForm" ng-controller="myController" 
     ng-submit="SubmitFunction(myForm)">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />            
    </form>
</div>

JS:
    var myApp = angular.module("MyApp",[]);
    myApp.controller("myController", ["$scope", function ($scope) {
        $scope.SubmitFunction = function (formElement) {
            //Set action attribute ???
           //Submit the form ????
        };           
    }]);
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Thanks for ur help. Finally found a solution.

```
<div ng-app="MyApp">
    <form name="myForm" ng-controller="myController" 
    ng-submit="SubmitFunction($event)">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />            
   </form>
</div>

JS:
var myApp = angular.module("MyApp",[]);
myApp.controller("myController", ["$scope", function ($scope) {
    $scope.SubmitFunction = function (e) {
        var formElement = angular.element(e.target);
        formElement.attr("action", actionLink);
        formElement.submit();
    };           
}]);
```